# Selenium method works only in debug mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've come up against a weird problem! I am a noobie Selenium Framework user, but anyway I use:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(xpath)).
```

This construction works in debug mode only, however, when I run test without debug, it seems like Compiler doesn't check this line.

Comment: How much time did you give it?

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Comment: And what makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I put sleep(1000) before WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); And it worked using Run mode also ))) But it seems strange for me ))

Comment: Make sure the `xpath` is correct and unique (matches only one element).

Comment: `xpath` is okay

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *not working*?

Comment: I have got a `login` method in which app shoul press the button, when a form becomes invisible `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(xpath));` However, button is not pressed and the compiler goes further. Although `sleep(1000)` helped, I think that a better solution exists

Answer (score 1):

It's a timing issue, the form might be considered invisible to the driver but the button is not loaded yet. In addition (or instead) to waiting for the form to disappear you should wait for the button to be visible and clickable

```
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(xpath));
button.click();
```